# How to get data from a selected data from the DataTables

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am trying to get selected data from DataTable but I'm unable to retrieve the data however I was able to retrieve the row index number. Anyone can help me to get the selected row data. I will provide a working fiddle for easier work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      'ajax': 'https://gyrocode.github.io/files/jquery-datatables/arrays_id.json',
      'columnDefs': [
         {
            'targets': 0,
            'checkboxes': {
               'selectRow': true
            }
         }
      ],
      'select': {
         'style': 'multi'
      },
      'order': [[1, 'asc']]
   });
   
   // Handle form submission event 
   $('#frm-example').on('submit', function(e){
      var form = this;
      
      var rows_selected = table.column(0).checkboxes.selected();

      // Iterate over all selected checkboxes
      $.each(rows_selected, function(index, rowId){
         // Create a hidden element 
         $(form).append(
             $('<input>')
                .attr('type', 'hidden')
                .attr('name', 'id[]')
                .val(rowId)
         );
      });

      // FOR DEMONSTRATION ONLY
      // The code below is not needed in production
      
      // Output form data to a console     
      $('#example-console-rows').text(rows_selected.join(","));
      
      // Output form data to a console     
      $('#example-console-form').text($(form).serialize());
       
      // Remove added elements
      $('input[name="id\[\]"]', form).remove();
       
      // Prevent actual form submission
      e.preventDefault();
   });   
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cvinhar/82csLoy5/

Comment: Hi. Get the selected data when? How? When you check the box and the submit button? The selected rows' data on submit? Please explain a little bit more with examples and I'll gladly take a look :)

Comment: Hi. When we tick the tick box and click on submit I want to get the name and position data instead of the rowId.

Answer (score 4):

You could simply use, inside your on submit :

```
let selectedValues = table.rows( { selected: true } ).data();
```

And then loop through your values.

Comment: This is a good solution. I want to add an remark that the select extension need to be loaded to make this work. Additional information: https://datatables.net/extensions/select/

Comment: Hi can I know how to loop through and get the data?

Comment: @Harvin Chandran sure but why is it a problem to loop through an array ?

Comment: You're already doing it in your code using your $.each, the hard part was getting the data...